# Running Jquery empty on a container with many children causing "unresponsive script" popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a container with about 6000 children all in all. Running Jquery.empty on this would take about 2 seconds on one of the faster browsers and on IE7/8 emptying it will quite often notify the user that the script is unresponsive and give the option to stop it.

Reading around here I've learned that I have to run Jquery.empty since I have some jquery bound objects to the elements and I want to avoid memory leaks.

Putting the empty in a setTimeout to relieve the "ui thread" doesn't seem to prevent the popup from appearing.

I need tips on how I can either speed this up or at least suppress the popup. Do I need to try and remove some elements or what affects the jquery.empty function? Can I break it up in two?

Code:

The DOM structure is the following:

```
<div class="table">
    <a id="header1">header1</a>
    <div id="content1">
         <a class="contenttext1">contenttext1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
         <a class="contenttext2">contenttext2</a>
    </div>
    ....content3
    ....content4
    ....
</div>
```

I am emptying the div.table with:

```
$(".table").empty();
```

Running $(".table").find("*").length gives 6000.

The .empty code takes around 2 seconds to run.

Comment: Can you post the code up please. You may have inefficient selectors that can be improved, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the script.

Comment: Code and structure added, thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$(".table").html('');` or just `$(".table")[0].innerHTML = '';`? As you can see in the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L185), `empty` gets every descendant and purges any data stored for them. This is good, but might be the cause for your problem.

Comment: One thing to add is there is no real solution to suppress the 'Slow script warning' popup message - you *can* stop it from happening, by altering the registry and the number of statements before it triggers, but really it's an awful solution that will never be feasible to implement

Comment: Yes, I've tried both .html('') and .innerHTML = ''. From what I've heard is that the innerHTML might not clean up all the jquery bound elements like empty or html('') would?

Comment: That could be, but the question is whether you have any data or event handlers bound to that elements anyway. If not, then don't worry. In any case, it would be interesting to know whether it is faster or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code I can't offer specific advice, but the two things I would do first are;

1.) Optimize your selectors so that the repeating code that is emptying the HTML from the DOM is as efficient as possible. IE8 & IE7 are notorious for being slower than other browsers, but by optimizing script you can negate this.

2.) Run the profiler in IE8 developer tools (for IE8 *and* IE8 Compat/IE7) and analyse where the bottleneck is in the results.

Comment: 1) I have code that returns the html as a string in the form of the DOM structure presented above. I then run $(".table").empty() and then $(".table").append() with the generated string. By putting timers around i've seen that is the $(".table").empty() instruction that is taking most of the time.

2) I've been trying to get IE8 dev tools to run but the browser seems to be crashing as soon as I bring it out on my page. (warning sign?) Profiling in chrome and firefox didn't give me any greater insight in bottlenecks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other API options for removing the elements, such as remove(), or the option suggested by Felix Kling above.